# How do I format XML in SQL Server from parameters?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces, for-xml

I am trying to make a wrapper parameterised stored procedure to execute another stored procedure which takes XML as its input (for use with SSRS).

This is how the XML stored procedure is currently run (the `@Xml` parameter is actually text type):

```sql
EXEC Report_Invoice @Xml = N'<XML><Params Date="2022-07-05T00:00:00" /><Customer KeyId="19" /><company KeyId="1" /><Department KeyId="1" /><Office KeyId="1" /></XML>'
```

I have come up with the following, but I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. How do I get the XML formatted properly?

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Report_Statement
    @EndDate SMALLDATETIME = NULL,
    @OfficeFilterBy INT = NULL,
    @DepartmentFilterBy INT = NULL,
    @companyFilterBy INT = NULL,
    @CustomerIdFilterBy INT = NULL
AS
    DECLARE @myXml Xml = (
        SELECT 
            Params.[Date],
            CustomerOffice.KeyId,
            Department.KeyId,
            company.KeyId,
            Customer.KeyId
        FROM
            (SELECT 1 AS ID, @EndDate AS [Date]) AS Params
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 1 AS ID, @OfficeFilterBy AS [KeyId]) CustomerOffice ON CustomerOffice.ID = Params.ID
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 1 AS ID, @DepartmentFilterBy AS [KeyId]) Department ON Department.ID = Params.ID
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 1 AS ID, @companyFilterBy AS [KeyId]) company ON company.ID = Params.ID
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 1 AS ID, @CustomerIdFilterBy AS [KeyId]) Customer ON Customer.ID = Params.ID
        FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ROOT('XML'))

    DECLARE @myXmlStr NVARCHAR(MAX) =  CAST( @myXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

    EXEC Report_Invoice @Xml = @myXmlStr
GO
```

Testing execution:

```sql
DECLARE @cDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

EXECUTE [dbo].Report_Statement 
   @EndDate = @cDate,
   @OfficeFilterBy = 1,
   @DepartmentFilterBy = 2,
   @companyFilterBy = 3,
   @CustomerIdFilterBy = 4
```

Produces this XML:

```xml
<XML>
  <Params Date="2022-07-05T23:16:00">
    <CustomerOffice KeyId="1">
      <Department KeyId="2">
        <company KeyId="3">
          <Client KeyId="4" />
        </company>
      </Department>
    </CustomerOffice>
  </Params>
</XML>
```

Comment: So what is your question? What isn't working as you require? What are you desired results?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the nesting of elements? Have you tried `PATH` mode instead of `AUTO`? Ref: [Examples: Use PATH mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-path-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you are using XML to pass parameters (in the deprecated `text` datatype no less), but it looks like you just need `FOR XML PATH` along with a XQuery path for each column name

```sql
DECLARE @myXmlStr nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT
      @EndDate AS [Params/@Date],
      @OfficeFilterBy AS [Office/@KeyId],
      @DepartmentFilterBy AS [Department/@KeyId],
      @companyFilterBy AS [company/@KeyId],
      @CustomerIdFilterBy AS [Customer/@KeyId]
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('XML')
);

EXEC Report_Invoice @Xml = @myXmlStr;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97b7cb9f4b348bf9043556abfc669ce7)

Comment: I didn't know how to use FOR XML PATH correctly, thank you this is exactly what I needed. The SP using the deprecated type is part of an external piece of software I cannot change without breaking it, hence the wrapper.